# C Programming sum of all integer numbers between two integers

Tags: c

I'm a newbie!

I'm supposed to get 2 integers from the user, and print the result(sum of all numbers between those two integers).

I also need to make sure that the user typed the right number.
The second number should be bigger than the first one.

And if the condition isn't fulfilled, I have to print "The second number should be bigger than the first one." and get the numbers from the user again until the user types right numbers that meet the condition.

So if I programmed it right, an example of the program would be like this.

> Type the first number(integer) : 10
>
> Type the second number(integer) : 1
>
> The second number should be bigger than the first one.
>
> Type the first number(integer) : 1
>
> Type the second number(integer) : 10
>
> Result : 55
>
> End

I think that I have to make two loops, but I can't seem to figure out how.
My English is limited, to help your understanding of this quiz, I'll add my flowchart below.

[image: Flowchart]

I tried many different ways I can think of, but nothing seems to work.
This is the code that I ended up with now.
But this doesn't work either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int total_sum = 0;
    printf("Type the first number : \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Type the second number : \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    while (a > b) {
        printf("The second number should be bigger than the first one.\n");
        printf("Type the first number : \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Type the second number : \n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    }
    while (a <= b) {
        total_sum += a;
        a++;
    }
    printf("Result : \n", total_sum);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In which way does it not work? Crash? Hang? Wrong output?

Comment: You forgot your format specifier on the last `printf` call.

Comment: seems like you're not even printing your results  from this line "printf("Result : \n", total_sum);" it should be printf("Result : %d\n", total_sum);

Comment: You should always compile your code with `-Wall` and read the warnings, this would have saved you this question ;)

Comment: Thank you, guys! I added format specifier on the last printf call and it worked... I spend all day to make it work, trying many different ways... and my last attempt was this code and it still didn't print the result so I asked you guys here and the problem was this silly mistake. I feel like a fool but at least I don't have to wrestle with this. so... I guess everything is good ;) Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I'd use google to check if there is a formula for the sum of n numbers (there is), you can make your program loads faster by getting rid of the loop. Also you may consider checking for overflow.

Comment: `(b + a) * (b - a + 1) / 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After corrections your code should run. The community has pointed out many mistakes in your code. Here's an amalgamated solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int correctInput=0;
    int total_sum = 0;
    do 
    {
        printf("Type the first number : \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Type the second number : \n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        if(a<b)
            correctInput=1;
        else 
            printf("The second number should be bigger than the first one.\n");
    }
    while (correctInput ==0) ;

    while (a <= b) {
        total_sum += a;
        a++;
    }
    printf("Result : %d \n" , total_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(a>b)` -> `if(a<b)`

Comment: also, type something not numeric and see a great endless loop ;)

Comment: You should check that the `scanf()` calls succeed.  You should probably limit the number of attempts, too, as a matter of semi-decent UI, though the question doesn't say that.  Ten is a good number; if they can't get it right in ten tries, they probably never will.

Comment: Answer should be able to stand on it's own. Don't rely on comments to explain things, as they might get removed. Without any explanation, this answer has very little value.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Mine worked too after I add format specifier for the last printf, but I think your answer would teach me a lot while I'm studying it. And thank you for editing my post too. I'll try to be specific and simple next time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using loop to sum the numbers, we can use mathematical formula.

**Sum of first N integers= N*(N+1)/2**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     int a = 0;
     int b = 0;
     int sum;

     //Run infinite loop untill a>b
     while(1)
     {
         printf("Type the first number : ");
         scanf("%d", &a);
         printf("Type the second number : ");
         scanf("%d", &b);
         if(a>b)
         {
             printf("The second number should be bigger than the first one.\n");
         }
         else
         {
             break;
         }
     }

     //Reduce comlexity of looping
     sum=((b*(b+1))-(a*(a-1)))/2;

     printf("Result : %d " , sum);
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Factorials are used frequently in probability problems. The factorial of a positive integer n (written n! and pronounced "n factorial") is equal to the product of the positive integers from 1 to n: n! = 1 x 2 x 3 x x n Write a program that takes as input an integer n and computes n!.